# Выделение запятыми придаточных предложений при использовании союза "не только...но и"

Tags: пунктуация, подчинительная-связь

Например, предложение

*Из кулинарной книги я узнал не только как варить суп с курицей но и для чего может пригодиться соль.*

Как здесь правильно расставить запятые?

Верно ли, что в этом случае работает [правило](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137):

> 4 Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:
>
> 2 ) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит
> сочинительный союз и, ни … ни, или, либо и т. п. (обычно
> повторяющийся): Учтите и что он сказал, и как он это сказал; Он не
> слышал ни как сестра вошла в комнату, ни как потом бесшумно вышла; Я
> отвечу на ваш запрос или когда прибудет очередной номер
> информационного бюллетеня, или когда сам наведу нужную справку; Не
> представлял себе и как выбраться из создавшегося положения; Я знаю и
> как это делается; Мальчика прощали и когда он никого не слушался.

И тогда правильным будет вариант

*Из кулинарной книги я узнал не только как варить суп с курицей, но и для чего может пригодиться соль.*

Comment: Это  именно то правило, которое следует применить. Вы очень хорошо знаете Розенталя и могли бы отвечать на вопросы.  Отвечающих здесь явно не хватает,  поэтому их любят (по крайней мере, первый год точно).